# C# - DataGridView - always display TopLeftHeaderCell

Tags: c#, winforms

is it possible to have TopLeftHeaderCell of DataGridView displayed even if the DataGridView contains no rows or columns?

Currently TopLeftHeaderCell is displayed when at least one column is present, but is not displayed when there is no columns and rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dummy column to Data Grid View and then set the visibility of that column to false.

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("dummyheader", "Dummy");
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, your gridview must contains columns , you can just print your TopLeftHeaderCell  if you don't have rows